# Procedure does not exist. Error 1305 MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, procedure

My server has been automatically updated from Mariadb 5.5.60 to 5.5.64.
From that moment on, no stored procedure is executed.
I get the error 1305: Procedure xxxx does not exist.
I've been reviewing privileges for hours and I can't find the problem.

Someone help me?

The Trigger user is `` `bduser`@`%` ``

This is the start of procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`bduser`@`%` PROCEDURE `dnpd_actualizar`(...
```

User `` `bduser`@`%` `` has granted: SUPER, EXECUTE, TRIGGER, and ALL PRIVILEGES and EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE.

Thanks.

Comment: Do `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE dnpd_actualizar`.  Does it exist?  Who was the definer?  What about the collation?

Comment: Yes, exists. The definer is bduser@% y the collation is utf8_general_ci. Thanks.